# Opening a file selection window from a java application

Tags: java, file, window, selection

How do I make my java application open one of those fancy file selection windows?
If you know, please tell me how to for both Mac and PC; It would help me a lot.
I searched google and StackOverflow, as well as some other sites, but just couldn't fnd what I was looking for. Btw, I'm still quite a noob at Java, so I wouldn't mind if you explain what your code does for me :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into `JFileChooser`. Here's the official [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). If you have specific followup questions, ask those.

Answer (score 10):

Use `FileChooser`:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame); //Where frame is the parent component

File file = null;
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    //Now you have your file to do whatever you want to do
} else {
    //User did not choose a valid file
}
```

For more information look at [How to Use File Chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).